# What type of relay/switch device am I looking for?

Tags: relay, switching, pulse

I want to control a 24V primary device based on a digital signal from a secondary device.

The secondary device emits a periodic pulse when I want the primary device to be ON and no periodic pulse is present when I want the primary device to be off.

I assume I need some type of relay, but I don't want the relay to turn ON & OFF with every pulse...I just want the relay to activate when the pulse is detected and remain active until the pulsing stops.

(I'm hoping to buy the pre-built switching device online, but I don't know what this type of switching system is called?)

Comment: What is the time between the periodic pulses, and how soon after the last pulse should the primary device be turned off?

Comment: I haven't measured the pulse rate; Let's assume 15 Hz. (If I need to calibrate the pulse rate for the timer via POT, etc., that is fine.)

Comment: I would like the primary device to turn off within a few seconds of the signal ceasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the pulse signal through a capacitor and a diode half bridge to the gate of a mosfet.

[image]

This will turn the mosfet on as long as the pulses are coming.

The mosfet will be off when the pulse train stops (hi or low doesn't matter)

The pulse voltage has to be large enough compared to the gate threshold of the mosfet. The 2N7002 has about 2.5V threshold voltage and the top schottky diode eats another ~0.2..0.3 V. So the minimum peak-to-peak pulse height has to be at least ~2.8V for this to work. If your pulses shape is smaller, then another mosfet with lower gate threshold voltage must be used.

R29, R30, C26 are optional.

R30 can be placed to discharge the gate faster, when the pulsing stops. Without R30, the gate discharges slowly due to leakage, which can take several seconds. The smaller R30, the faster the turnoff.

C26 has the opposite effect, it increases the charge available at the gate node, making turn-off due to the leakage slower. It also makes the turn-on slower though. If you want instant turn-on within 1-2 pulses, then C26 should be well smaller than C25.

R29 is there to limit the peak current from the pulsing IO pin. If C26 is small or missing, R29 may not be needed either and can be replaced with a short.

The capacitor voltage rating in the schematic can be ignored, they should be able to work with the pulse voltage, which is usually low (e.g. 3.3 V), but higher voltage spec doesn't hurt.

Comment: Like this, well done.

Comment: Impressive, I wish I had the ability to design the requested circuit off the top of my head!

Comment: Do you know, is a prebuilt version of this available online?

Comment: I don't know Charles. I have built it years ago and used it as a failsafe relay since. It is very robust ( no failure yet) and you can tune the on/off times with the resistors. The bat54, 2n7002 are commodity products that cost much less and are smaller than the relay itself. So any integrated component would be much more expensive/specialized/proprietary.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for all your help! @tobalt thank you fur the schematic -- I'll likely give this circuit a try once I get back home to my equipment. Your willingness to share is much appreciated!

Comment: @CharlesT. good luck. I will add a little more info to my answer, what the role of the optional parts is and when they are needed.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanations, @tobalt!

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re looking for a timer relay or timer switch, I don’t think there’s standard terminology.  These devices come in several different varieties that do slightly different things.  What you’ll need is a relay that you can set to switch on for a little more than the time between pulses, and one that can re-trigger so that it stays switched on continuously.  Such devices certainly exist, I’ll see if I can track down an example...

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. I'm finding a lot of timer circuits on Amazon, but they seem to be missing the option to trigger via pulse signal. I'm sure I must be searching with the wrong terms

Comment: I was just looking at this http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1682139.pdf which can do a bunch of things but not quite what you’re looking for.  Watch this space.

Comment: Thanks for the link; I thinkI saw a similar switch from the same manufacturer, but like you said it doesn't exactly fit the bill. I do appreciate the effort yoo made to help locate a ready-to-use solution!

Answer (score 0):

Need a timer to "listen to the signal and open the relay when the pulses stop.

So, the timer has to have an "on" duration of the "off" time of the pulse.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a pre-built switching device available that would allow me to specify that parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Recently went down a similar rabbit hole, if a pre-built switching system is what you are looking for something like [this](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/relays_-z-_timers/timer_relays/t2r-m2-adj-240u) may work well, a programmable/multi-function time delay relay w/ watchdog retriggerable single shot control paradigm. Function graph below:
[image]