# A GPIO that will keep HIGH when running and LOW when sleep?

Tags: gpio, esp32, sleep

Is there a GPIO that is automatically HIGH when the ESP32 is running and LOW when it's asleep?

I'm aware I can choose an arbitrary one and set it to HIGH on boot; I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing an obvious one. I want to use it as a switch to power off peripherals when the board goes into sleep mode.

Comment: The issue is that the pin would remain HI, when your software bugs out or at least it will be in an undefined state. If you wish a failsafe HI while running and a failsafe LO otherwise, use a charge pump architecture (capacitor and diode) and toggle the pin actively..See here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/560926/237061

Comment: You could use a RTC-GPIO with a pull-up (50k?) to make it automatically high when powered on and switch it to 0 when you want the devices to stop (this would still be 0 when sleeping). This is only possible when using with an EN pin on the devices or a mosfet to switch on/off, not when you feed the peripherals by the GPIO pins..

Comment: Thanks! I don't intend for the pin to switch the device off, just be an indicator of whether its running or sleeping. The peripheral is not drawing current from this pin but it would turn itself off if receive a LOW signal.
I noticed that when I set a GPIO to LOW and then go to (deep)sleep, the voltage raises to around 0.2-0.3V instead of 0 and I guess its just floating. I also tried to use RTC GPIOs hoping they would keep their state, but failed...