# Smooth a PWM to DC stable

Tags: transistors, pic, pwm, filter

I have to smooth a PWM (0V- 12V, 200Hz) who trigger my pic12f1572 via transistor 2N3904. What is the best way?

I have PWM source connected to 2N3904 and output from 2N3904 is connected to PIC uc. I want to set pin of uc ON when PWM is available and set pin of when PWM is off.
Should work RC filter? How can I design the circuit?
Thanks!

Comment: When PWM source is **OFF**, what state is it in? (+12V, 0V, high impedance)? How much *delay* can your PWM-sensing circuit tolerate. *Delay* being the time span between PWM becoming available, and pic12F1572 detecting it...and delay also being the time span between PWM going OFF and pic12F1572 un-detecting it.

Comment: When you write "smooth a PWM to DC stable" it means one thing to me, but you don't seem to care about the DC level at all? Do you want to remove noise from the PWM but keep the pulses? Detecting the existence is likely easier without any smoothing, but the question is unclear to me.

Comment: Why not to sense if the pwm is presented in MCU without additional circuitry? If not just ping the monostable circuit with pwm edges and read the output of monostable with MCU.

Answer (score 0):

You usually do this with an RCD network as sketched below, no transistor necessary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcwKF2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 is optional. It can be replaced by an internal pull-down of the pin, if the PIC has such a thing.

If the PWM can actually remain "off" in the 12V state, then you need a capacitor to decouple its DC value, as is shown [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/560926/237061).

Comment: You're welcome!